# How to allow a checkbox to be empty in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I have defined the following variable within an entity in my application. I have this, among other fields that can be updated via a form interface and I wish to be able to check and uncheck this box on that form.

I can check the box and submit the form fine, but it seems that when I uncheck the box, I can't submit the form. It gives me a `Please check this box if you want to proceed`.

```
/**
 * @var boolean $updatesNeeded
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="updates_needed", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
private $updatesNeeded;
```

I tried changing `nullable=false` to `nullable=true` and updating the schema, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class BlahType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder $builder
     * @param array                               $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('stuff')
            ->add('updatesNeeded', 'choice', array('required' => false))
            ->add('anothervar');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

This error is because the input is marked with the HTML5 attribute `required="required"`. In your form type you can disable this by setting the `required` option to false on this checkbox.

```
$builder->add('updatesNeeded', 'choice', array('required' => false));
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-forms-html5-validation-disable

Comment: I looked at the html and it does seem that there is `required="required"` in the input tag. However, this solution didn't seem to do anything for me. I edited the `Bundle/Form/EntityType.php` file's `buildForm` function. Is that the right place?

Comment: that would be the place. are there any other fields with the `required` attribute? Is the error message you get coming from chrome or from symfony?

Comment: The other fields also have the `required` attribute. I'm actually using firefox and it's coming from that.

Comment: ya that's definitely the problem then. You'll need to disable the `required` attribute. Make sure you clear caches when changing the form type.

Comment: Posted and tried to follow this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html

Comment: I recall having problems with the required attribute as well. I ended up disabling the form's client-side validation with `<form novalidate...>`.

Answer (score -1):

What about just using `nullable=""`

Comment: This yields a column equivalent to making nullable equal to false

Answer (score -3):

Okay it seems that I was using the wrong version of my site. All of the methods mentioned work, and I just want to summarize them below for anyone who runs into such a problem in the future.

The issue here is that HTML5 likes to validate forms by itself and adds a `required="required"` to any form input. Usually, this is probably a useful thing, but for some things like checkboxes, you want the option of leaving them unchecked and submitting the form without the browser complaining on the client side.

There are several ways to solve this problem, some better than others.

The first is to simply disable all validation for the form using HTML5, as mentioned by the official [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-forms-html5-validation-disable).

Another is to add information to the entity variable in the comments, making `nullable=true`. This allows the corresponding column in your database to have null values, which may or may not be desirable for your situation. This is shown below.

```
/**
 * @var boolean $varName
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="var_name", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $varName;
```

Finally, when building the form, there are certain options that you can use for validation in the forms. The [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-validation) detail and give more examples, but for our purposes here, the important part is that you can set `'required' => false`, as I've shown below.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class BlahType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder $builder
     * @param array                               $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('stuff')
            ->add('checkbox_var', 'checkbox', array('required' => false))
            ->add('anothervar');
    }
}
```

Thank you to all the people who helped me with this issue. I hope this helps someone who has to deal with these sorts of issues in the future.